# Login window doesn't pop in Chrome when requesting HTTPS

Tags: flash, google-chrome, https

I have an application that communicates with HTTPS services that require login.

On every browser other than Chrome (v 22.0.1229.94) once the HTTPS request is made, a browsers own login window pops and asks for authentication.
As you might have guessed, in Chrome it doesn't happen and all the HTTPS requests return 401. If you go directly to such request, however, the login window pops and once logged-in, retrieves the response properly.

Is that a limitation of the Chrome internal flash plugin or is it something else maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the login popup is blocked when the requesting application runs on a domain different from the one of the requested service.

When domains match, everything's working fine. For other cases - use Firefox.